# 9 dots Show Application menu stucks once in a while in ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04

[image: ow]

The 9 dots show application menu opens good,works good usually.But, once in a while it gets stuck like this.Not only it stuck alone,it stops whole system,No buttons or super button work at all.Only option is to switch off the machine by pressing power button.Is this a bug everyone facing?or there is a solution around?
Thanks

Comment: it is actually an resulation issue,which has awork around aka fix

Comment: Hi I have encountered exactly this problem. Would you mind sharing a fix? I have some programs running in terminal, so I cannot just switch off my comp. My mouse and keyboard is working so i can write in "search menu" but no keyboard shortcut is working, no alt+tab, if there is any other way how to access my terminal?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNSaI.jpg)